# Menu bar not displayed on window.open for Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, menubar, window.open

When I run the JavaScript code below in Mozilla Firefox, the menu bar does not show:

```
                window.open(location.pathname + "?print=print",
                    "print-window",
                    "toolbar=yes,location=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes");
```

What is going wrong here?

Note that I'm opening the same file (in another window), I'm just adding a parameter value to it.  I don't know whether this matters.

Strangely enough, if I call:

```
                    window.print();
```

on the new window, the menu bar does show.

Comment: What version of Firefox, and what OS? Works for me on Firefox 3.03 / Windows XP.

Comment: menubar=yes works for me (Firefox 9.0.1, Windows XP)

Comment: Tip: don't use spaces in the features list. Some browsers may not understand the parameters after a space. @PaulReiners I see you don't put spaces there, but it's a tip for other people reading this and a common issue.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried menubar=1 ... or possibly menubar=true?

Comment: Sorry.  I take that back.  menubar=1 does work.  Thanks!  Now I need to check whether it works with other browsers.